# How to Change a tfs bug into a feature request

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Is there a way to move an existing TFS bug to a feature request via direct db manipulation, power tool, or otherwise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

Once a work item is assigned to a particular type you can't just migrate it.  You *probably* could do it through direct db manipulation but this has a very high probability of breaking your TFS server.  Don't do it.

What you should be doing is closing the bug and recreating it as a feature request while establishing a link between the two.

Obligatory link to a MS response on this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-MY/tfspowertools/thread/02a9d0e3-c944-43f1-886d-8603d11e0ced

Comment: To the OP, I would definitely avoid the recommendation in the MS response to delete the original work item.  Definitely overkill, plus it destroys the historical accountability that closing/linking provides.

Comment: I agree: don't delete the original.  Just close it and associate a link to the new one.